# What is the gramatical term for the beneficiary in a subject-verbs-object sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm writing a web-component where the user is supposed to change some element.

The application allows the user to change the same kind of element in two or more contexts.

The user interface should read something like:

- You are changing a table in {the room} bedroom.
- You are changing the tiles of {the floor} in bathroom.

*this is not a custom-appartment app*

- You are swapping out an ingredient in {recipe} Chocolate cake.
- Your character is trying on a garment on {the body part} head.

In gramatical analysis, we have devices like subject, object, verb, ad-verb, pronomen and those comprise the total of my knowledge on the subject.

The question is; is there a generic name for the component inticated between the curly braces? I *need* to know this because of an obsession with logically sound or semantically correct variable names.

So the component is none of the mentioned above (I think), but the *beneficiary* of, or *someone who is affected by* the subject-verbs-object sentence.

Comment: (1) The names of parts of speech (word classes) should not be confused with semantic and syntactic roles. (2) The object of a preposition is often called an *oblique*, especially when it plays a defined semantic role vis-a-vis the action of the verb.

Comment: It sounds like a *category*. The word following the curly brackets is one of the possible *values* of that category. However, English sentences aren't normally written in the manner of your examples, with or without curly brackets. In your examples, the bracketed terms are *meta information* rather than parts of speech.

Comment: Would you use the word 'target' as the end part or outcome of the workflow process?